# Php mysql query array stores 2 fields in each array index

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

When I try to `mysql_fetch_row` the array that is created contains 2 fields from my selection at each index. I would like to ask why is this happening?

```
<?php
  $categoryid = $_GET['id']; 
  include('connect.php');

  $query = "SELECT
           Categories_SubCategories.IdCategory,Categories_SubCategories.idSub_Category,
           Categories.Name, Sub_Categories.Name from Categories_SubCategories JOIN 
           Categories on Categories.idCategory = Categories_SubCategories.idCategory  
           JOIN Sub_Categories on Categories_SubCategories.idSub_Category =
           Sub_Categories.idSub_Category
           WHERE Categories_SubCategories.IdCategory = $categoryid";

  $result = mysql_query($query);
  $rows = mysql_num_rows($result);

  for($i=0; $i<$rows; $i++){
     $display = mysql_fetch_row($result);
     echo "$display[3]";
  }
?>
```

Comment: apply coding style to your code ...

Comment: Please stop writing new code with the ancient mysql_* functions. They are no longer maintained and community has begun the [deprecation process](http://news.php.net/php.internals/53799). Instead you should learn about prepared statements and use either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli). If you care to learn, [here is a quite good PDO-related tutorial](http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

most PHP programmers use `while()` loop when they want to work with `mysql_fetch_array()`.

Take a look at this sample code:

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT id,name FROM tbl_members");
if (mysql_num_rows($query)) {
    while ($result = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
        echo('User #'.$result['id'].' is: '.$result['name'].'<br />');
    }
}

// Output can be something like this:
// User #1 is: John
// User #2 is: Sarah
```

Comment: `mysql_fetch_row` won't allow you to access the array with `$result['id']`.

Comment: @MrCode, you are right. It was my mistake. I meant `mysql_fetch_array`. Thank you for your comment

Comment: @user1031654 please pay attention that I changed `mysql_fetch_row()` to `mysql_fetch_array()` in order to access to the results by their names. You can use `mysql_fetch_row()` when you would like to work with index numbers

Answer (score 0):

replace `mysql_num_rows` with `mysql_fetch_array` or `mysql_fetch_assoc`

Comment: I think it should be: "replace `mysql_fetch_row` with `mysql_fetch_assoc`" like @MrCode is implying in a comment on the accepted answer.